# Issue while importing package

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am facing weird issue while importing library into my code which say Unexpected token {

I am importing Protractor library into my code and it throws error message saying '{' is not expected

```
import {ElementFinder} from "protractor"
import {by} from "protractor"


function selectByIndex(index:number, dropdown:ElementFinder){
    this.dropdown = dropdown;
    dropdown.click()
    // browser.sleep(1000)
    index = index + 1;
    console.log("Selecting element based index : "+index)
    // select the option
    this.dropdown.element(by.css("option:nth-child("+index+")")).click()
}
module.exports = selectByIndex;
```

I am expecting library import should be resolved, but getting below
Error message:

```
[22:31:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[22:31:23] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[22:31:26] E/launcher - Error: /Users/pradeepnayak/Protractor_Learning/utils/Select.ts:5
import {ElementFinder} from "protractor"
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:694:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
[22:31:26] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: Are you using typescript? If not have you configured babel?

Comment: It appears you are using typescript but either way it is never necessary import protractor directly within your scripts. All of those modules will be initialized when protractor starts and available in all test files. Can you remove those two imports from Protractor and try once again

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
import ElementFinder from "protractor"
```